# Why is CSP require-sri-for marked as obsolete?

Tags: content-security-policy

The [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/require-sri-for) from Mozilla warns that `require-sri-for` is obsolete and may be removed at any time.

The feature seems useful, especially for large websites where it's likely that a developer may forget to include an integrity attribute.

Is there a specific reason this has been deprecated? Is there an alternative feature to use instead?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/184103

Comment: @kristian - Doesn't seem related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox 68 for developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/68#HTTP) explains:

> The Content-Security-Policy directive require-sri-for is no longer supported due to concerns about its standardization status. It was previously available only behind a preference, which was off by default (bug 1386214).

Hopefully it will be back when the directive is standardized.